# I need help for an Update done in a specific way

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i will describe as much as possible my problem. Its a little bit hard to explain but i will try.

Basically i work on a Oracle's Framework called MDM and i can't change logic or table design. The lucky thing is that the table that i am using is Custom so its not under the framework.

The table is set like this:

```
|DOMAIN|SECOND_NAME|SOME_VALUES|
|   X  |     XX    |28309128312|
|   X  |     XX    |11121309011|
|   Y  |     YY    |55583202300|
|   Z  |     ZZ    |00000912323|
```

As you can see, the table has 3 columns;
one called domain, the second one called second_name and the third one called some_values.

The logic about this Table is:
For every domain there are many occurrences for every value that domain can hire.

So if i have domain X i can find in my table many different records that will have different value but the same Domain.

The real problem is:

For every domain is associated a second_name like an alias.
The alias will not change based on the SOME_VALUES, if a record has domain = x the second name will be XX.

I have a list of second_name value on a Excel sheet and i have to update the column SECOND_NAME with that.

Is it possible to write an update script that for every domain called X i will write in second_name xx, for every domain called Y i will write in second_name YY and so on.

I have 109 domain and of course 109 second_name, but in the table there are something like 20.000 records and of course there are some with the same domain like the Example table up.

Comment: Desired results would really help.

Comment: Do you have the `domain` and `second_name` values in a table already? in that case you just need a join update

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the content of the Excel file in a database table called `my_mapping`, with columns `domain` and `second_name`, you could execute this simple `UPDATE` statement, that uses a correlated subquery to recover the relevant `second_name`:

```
UPDATE mytable t SET second_name = (
    SELECT m.second_name
    FROM my_mapping m
    WHERE m.domain = t.domain
);
```

The combination of both columns in the mapping table should be unique.